# grub error 15: file not found

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, redhat, grub

I have a vm(on vmware fully running). But i want to do some modification and put all file system to single partition /.

In my current VM i have /, /var, /tmp, /boot partition.

Action performed:

1. Attached new hard disk, formatted and created two partition (one for / and another for swap)
2. made / as active partition for root.
3. copied all the files from original hard disk to new harddisk.
4. made changes in /etc/fstab and run grub-install.
5. detached new harddisk and created new VM using this harddisk.

Now when I am starting VM, I got

> "Error 15: File not found"

Comment: Probably `grub-install` was done in the wrong hd, did you [specify the destination device](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall)?

Comment: Yes Alex, i did specified the right hd, also i booted new VM from rhel 6.5 dvd in rescue mode and executed following command.

1. chroot /mnt/sysimage
2. grub-install /dev/sda (executed successfully)

Still not working.

Answer (score -1):

Just got answer while hitting and trying . This error is due to /etc/grub/grub.conf file. When we have /boot partition we don't need to give whole path for kernel for example :

Kernel /< kernel version>

but when we have single root partition only, means no /boot partition we need to provide complete path, example:

Kernel /boot/< kernel version>

And same for initrd line.

It worked for me.

Comment: Have you considered in accepting this answer? It is perfectly fine to accept your own answer.